# Which code is read first when I start my program?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

Which part of my C# code is first read when I start my program?

I would like to instantly close the application if a debugger is attached, so where do I put my if (Debugger.IsAttached) code? I've tried putting it inside Program.cs (Main) and I've also tried putting it right after "InitializerComponent();" in "public Form1()" Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/fgl6ql 
Screenshot of Program.cs: http://prntscr.com/fgl6zu

Comment: Please don't post *screenshots* of code - post the code as *text*. Next, you say you've tried two things - what happened in each case? (Basically, the `Main` method executes - that's what's calling your `Form1` constructor, note...)

Comment: If you want to close it immidiately, then why do you put that code after the `InitializeComponent();` instead of before?

Comment: When putting it inside main I got no results, when putting it after InitializerComponent(); I didn't get any results either. The only time I got effect was when I put it inside my button and after the button was clicked, I would like it to exit instantly

Comment: Debugger can be attached at any point of execution of your code.  Not necessarily at the start of execution (typically `Main` function).  So checking for debugger at the start of program won't necessarily prevent someone from debugging your program using debugger :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever is in `Main()` is executed first, that's usually always the entry point for .NET Console/Windows Applications.

Answer (score -1):

LB2 made a good point, so I will add a bunch of

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached){
Application.Exit();}
```

in my code at various locations.
Thanks @LB2